# Element offset returns 0 when element is shown rather than real value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please run the snippet in full page. I am trying to use the offset function. But I am facing some issue here. Offset function returns 0 while hovering but it returns real value while leaving the hover. So I am not getting the real value when the element is shown to the screen. How can I get the real value while the element is shown?

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});

$('.dropdown-toggle').parent().hover(function() {
    var menu = $(this).find("ul");
    var menupos = $(menu).offset();
    console.log(menupos);
    if (menupos.left + menu.width() > $(window).width()) {
        var newpos = -$(menu).width();
        menu.css({ left: newpos });    
    }
});
```

```css
/* bootstrap dropdown hover menu*/

body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4f5d6e;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(26, 49, 95);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(10%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(29, 108, 141, 1)), color-stop(37%, rgba(41, 136, 151, 1)), color-stop(77%, rgba(39, 45, 100, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(26, 49, 95, 1)));
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a315f', endColorstr='#1a315f', GradientType=0);
}

nav {
  margin-top: 60px;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is because when you hover the animation/transition is not yet complete, so you are getting incorrect coordinates. If you want to get the correct position, do it in the callback in the `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap and there are Bootstrap events bind over the given dropdown just add your code right after the event is executed.

Set your conditions as described in the documentation [Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns-events) (you might need to check Bootstrap 4 events instead)

If you feel more comfy overriding Bootstrap, firsthand disable all the events already bind with the given element, i.e.

```
$( '.dropdown' ).off( );
```

Or, use **show.bs.dropdown**, **shown.bs.dropdown**, **hide.bs.dropdown**, **hidden.bs.dropdown**. To be more exact use shown and hidden events. So

```
$( '.dropdown' ).on( 'shown.bs.dropdown, hidden.bs.dropdown', function( ) {  
    var menu = $(this).children('ul');
    var menupos = menu.offset();
    console.log(menupos);
    if (menupos.left + menu.width() > $(window).width()) {
        var newpos = -$(menu).width();
        menu.css({ left: newpos });    
    }
} );
```

I haven't tested that but it should give you the expected result